# Facebook Open Graph Protocol - different versions of admin page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm using the Facebook open graph protocol on several pages on my site.  I understand that each unique URL will have a different admin URL (as shown in the linter tool), however, there appear to be atleast 2 different versions of this administrative interface.

The best way to illustrate is by example - the first image below shows a screenshot of the Facebook admin interface for the site's home page.  The second shows a screenshot of the admin interface for one of the inside pages.  One obvious difference, for example, is that the second page includes a "Get Started" link in the left-hand navigation bar.

The only og: tags which differ on those pages are image, title and url.  All the other tags (including app_id) are the same.

Would really appreciate it if someone could explain the reason for the different admin interfaces?

Screenshot 1
[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook [upgraded their Business page format](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-pages/an-upgrade-for-pages/10150090729064822) back in February. Maybe they are different versions.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The strange part is that the site was just a twinkle in my eye in February.  Maybe it took them a while to roll out the new format?

Any advice on how I might be able to cleverly recreate/upgrade my page without losing my likes?

PS. Thanks OffBySome for editing my post and embedding the images...  Very cool that trusted senior members can do this!